# Powershell find a string after specific line

Tags: powershell

I have a log file that appends a "restart successfully" line after each restart. Starting from the last "restart successfully" line, I want to find any lines after that contain a word from a list of search words.

How can I do this? I have partly working code below:

```
$contentsOfLog = Get-Content $inputFile
$keyWords =  $contentsOfLog | Select-String 'restart successfully'
$linenumbers = $keyWords.LineNumber
$linenumber = $linenumbers[$linenumbers.Length - 1]

$inputLines = ""

For ($i=$linenumber; $i -lt $contentsOfLog.length; $i++) {
    $line = $contentsOfLog[$i]
    $line = $line|select-string -pattern $error|Out-String
    $inputLines += $line.TrimEnd()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obtain the line number to start from with a first pass through `Select-String` like you've already found, then use `Select-Object -Skip` to skip the lines prior:

```
$contentsOfLog = Get-Content $inputFile
$startFrom = $contentsOfLog |Select-String 'restart successfully' |Select -Last 1 -Expand LineNumber

$inputLines = $contentsOfLog |Select -Skip $startFrom |Select-String $error |Select -Expand Line
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mathias as always :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limit on the expected number of lines after your search string, then you can use `Select-String'`s `-Context` switch:

```
$contentsOfLog = Get-Content $inputFile
($contentsOfLog | Select-String 'restart successfully' -Context 0,999).Context.PostContext | Select-String $error
```

This has the advantage that you're parsing in one pass, but the disadvantage that you need to have a limit on the number of lines searched.  Note that setting the second number (999 in my example) to a ridiculously high value slows it down, and any value higher than System.Int32 can store will cause an error.